# Activate AutoPredictor not showing in aws forecast

Tags: amazon-web-services

so basically the button to enable or disable AutoPredictor in AWS Forecast is not showing up. It used to show up in other consoles i've used. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I don¿t see any update about removing this button.

[image]